# LINQ sorting of property List in List of custom object

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have two lists of objects, each object has the property Recommendations which itself is a list of 'Recommendation' objects. I want to sort the recommendation objects based on one of its properties. I have come up with this:

```
TPSqlORs.Where(x => x.Recommendations != null)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(y => y.Recommendations.OrderBy(z => z.PointNumber));
SbmReportsORs.Where(x => x.Recommendations != null)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(y => y.Recommendations.OrderBy(z => z.PointNumber));
```

But it causes no change at all to the original lists, which makes me suspect the `ToList()` is just making a copy and the sorting is happening on a copy which gets lost after execution. I searched along these lines but apparently whilst it does make a copy, the new list contains references to the original list elements, so surely it should be sorting them for both lists?

Comment: Please break your habit always to use `ToList().ForEach`. The `ToList` creates a fresh new collection from the first, so you are wasting cpu-cycles and even more memory just to be able to use `List.ForEach` instead of `foreach`. In this case you're even using it more superfluously since you can chain `OrderBy` directly behind `Where`.

Comment: Exactly what type is `Recommendations`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `List<Recommendation>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Recommendations` is in fact a `List<Recommendation>` you can sort it in-place using `List.Sort()`:

```
item.Recommendations.Sort((lhs, rhs) => lhs.PointNumber.CompareTo(rhs.PointNumber));
```

This assumes that `item` is the object which contains the `Recommendations` that you want to sort.

If `Recommendation` elements in the list can be null, you can handle it like this:

```
item.Recommendations.Sort
(
    (lhs, rhs) =>
    (lhs == null || rhs == null)
    ? Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(lhs, rhs) 
    : lhs.PointNumber.CompareTo(rhs.PointNumber)
);
```

See [`List.Sort(Comparison<T> comparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) for details.

Note that `List.Sort()` is an *unstable* sort, while `Enumerable.OrderBy()` is a stable sort, but this is unlikely to make a difference to your case. You need to be aware of the difference though.

[Edit: I have incorporated the code from Jeppe Stig Nielsen's comment below; my thanks to him.]

Comment: Can you illustrate how this would best be done from your experience when `item` is within a `List<item>` and some of those items may have no Recommendations (`null`)

Comment: @deed02392 Do you mean the `Recommendation` itself can be null? Then you could do something like `(lhs, rhs) => lhs == null || rhs == null ? Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(lhs, rhs) : lhs.PointNumber.CompareTo(rhs.PointNumber)`. I assume that `PointNumber` is a non-nullable value type?

Comment: Correct @JeppeStigNielsen, thanks for this update. This answer is clearer IMO.

Answer (score 4):

`OrderBy` is not changing order of list. If you want changing order you should write:

```
y.Recommendations = y.Recommendations.OrderBy(z => z.PointNumber).ToList()
```

Read about [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

Comment: You'd probably want a `ToList` call as well - to avoid re-ordering every time it's accessed, apart from anything else.

Comment: Should this be within the `ForEach`? If I replace as you've described I am told `y` does not exist in the context.

Comment: @deed02392 replace your `y.Recommendations.OrderBy(z => z.PointNumber)` with line above

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy` will never change the order of the original list. It, along with the other LINQ methods, are pure functions. They don't modify the inputs and only create new outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the LINQ expressions don't do changes to the source, they return a resulting collection.

Comment: Here it's `IOrderedEnumerable`